# Run Non GUI Jar Files

Tags: java

I know that I can run non GUI jar files from the command line. Is there any way that can do so by clicking or something and not writing the commands again and again.? Is there any software to do so. ( I am talking about a  compiled jar and don't want to run from any ide)

Comment: And what does the program do? If you double click on the jar file, it should run as long as you've configured your OS to recognize the jar extension. Now, how will you see what the program does -- that's the question for me.

Comment: On Windows, you can create a shortcut with the command you are running (i.e. `java -jar yourJarFile.jar`). I suppose in Unix / Linux environments you can do something similar

Comment: I am on windows and am trying to run a simple program that takes user input and .......

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String TITLE = "CONSOLE title";
public static final String FILENAME = "myjar.jar";
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    if(args.length==0 || !args[args.length-1].equals("terminal")) {
        String[] command;
        if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
            command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start \"title \\\""+TITLE+"\\\" & java -jar \\\""+new File(FILENAME).getAbsolutePath()+"\\\" terminal\""};
        } else {
            command =new String[]{"sh", "-c", "gnome-terminal -t \""+TITLE+"\" -x sh -c \"java -jar \\\""+new File(FILENAME).getAbsolutePath()+"\\\" terminal\""};
        }
        try {
            Process p  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
        } catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //THERE IS YOUR CONSOLE PROGRAM:
        System.out.println("Hey! What's your name?");
        String read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
        System.out.println("Hey, "+read+"!");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

You can run it with double clicking on .jar file. Don't forget about MANIFEST.MF! :) (working on linux, also!)

Example (I only double clicked on jar file):
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

The way intended by Java is that you call `java -jar XXXX.jar` on the jars you need. Drawback is that you can't specify a classpath so all classes should be there.

A cooler way to package an application is by using Java WebStart. With that the user installs the application jut by clicking on a web browser. Check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html

Comment: He want to write program, where you double click on JAR file and it will be open in console.